# ServiceStack - FluentValidation

Tags: c#, servicestack, fluentvalidation

I have a question about using a FluentValidation with ServiceStack.

For example:

```
[Route("/customers/{Id}", "PUT")]
public class UpdateCustomer : IReturn<Customer>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Route("/customers/{Id}", "DELETE")]
public class DeleteCustomer : IReturnVoid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm updating customer info, I want to validate for example all params, but when deleting it for example, I just want to make sure that Id is for example positive int. So, FirstName, LastName, etc. everything else I don't care in that case.

If I implement FluentValidator on Customer class, I will have to put all the logic inside the validator for that (to apply different rules based on request route)? Or there's more elegant way for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validators should only be on the Request DTO's, e.g:

```
public class UpdateCustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<UpdateCustomer>
{
    public UpdateCustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.Id).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(r => r.FirstName).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(r => r.LastName).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

and likewise for `DeleteCustomer`, e.g:

```
public class DeleteCustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<DeleteCustomer>
{
    public DeleteCustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.Id).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

Although creating a whole validator for a single field can be overkill so you could instead just add the validation in your Service, e.g:

```
public class CustomerServices : Service
{
    public void Any(DeleteCustomer request)
    {
        if (request.Id <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Id Required", "Id")

        Db.DeleteById<Customer>(request.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I realize how silly my question was :)

BTW, in the case above, is it a big deal using a response dto like that? I mean not following the naming convention from servicestack pattern, e.g. **UpdateCustomerResponse**, **CreateCustomerResponse**, it will be also overkill to have basically duplicated that **Customer** response dto.

Comment: @ShP Benefits of using a specific Response DTO is being able to evolve the Service (i.e. adding more properties) without breaking the Service Contract (so existing clients continue to work). It's also required for SOAP, otherwise you don't need it.